# How to load output from the kegg API in biopython into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, kegg, pandas

Biopython provides a (bit unintuitive) API to access to the Kyoto Encyclopedia of Genes and Genomes ([KEGG](https://www.genome.jp/kegg/)). I am trying to make use of it, but the output is quite unhandy as a string. What is the best way to parse the data into a `pandas.DataFrame()`?

```
from Bio.KEGG import REST as Kegg
import io

pd.read_table(kegg.kegg_get('K02545'))
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide an example of the output so it is easier understand why this string is not useful, and how it relates to your coded solution.

Answer (score 1):

*solution from @sören:*

I came up with this solution for my problem:

```
from Bio.KEGG import REST as kegg

def _get_kegg(kegg_id):
    kegg_output = kegg.kegg_get(kegg_id).read()
    results = {}
    for line in kegg_output.split('\n'):
        splits = line.split()
        if not line.startswith(' '):    
            if len(splits) > 0:
                key = splits[0]
                value = ' '.join(splits[1:])
                results[key] = value
        else:
            results[key] += ' '.join(splits)
    return pd.DataFrame(results, index=[kegg_id])


_get_kegg_v = np.vectorize(_get_kegg)

def get_kegg_info(kegg_ids):
    if isinstance(kegg_ids, str):
        kegg_ids = [kegg_ids]
    return pd.concat(_get_kegg_v(kegg_ids), sort=False)
```